# How to make `model.fit` stop training immediately when called on a naive model that does not have trainable layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am writing a training pipeline for time series forecasting models. I am using a naive seasonal model as baseline, which just outputs the last `out_steps` of the input.

```
class Naive(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, out_steps: int,
             **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.out_steps = out_steps

def call(self, inputs, training=None):
    features = inputs

    return features[:, -self.out_steps:, :]
```

I then can use the generic training stage:

```
def train_model(model_name, **model_params):
    model = instantiate_model(model_name, **model_params)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(train_dataset)
```

Is there a way to make `fit` understand that the model has no trainable layers and stop immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a one-line wrapper:

```
if model.trainable_variables:
    model.fit(...)
```

`model.trainable_variables` contains the, well, trainable variables, for a model without such variables, this will be empty and the if condition is False.

NOTE though, that if you create models using `Sequential`, and did not provide an input shape in the first layer, and also did not call the `build()` function of the model, such a model will also not have any variables before calling `fit`! These will only be created once the model is called for the first time. So you have to be careful with this, or add something like this:

```
if model.trainable_variables:
    model.fit(...)
elif not model.built:
    raise SomeError  # or print a warning
```